# link for max characters in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

Ive got a js that runs to see if a maximum amount of characters is reached. Its got text along with href, but when the max amount of characters is reached, the link doesnt work and converts it to just text. When the limit of less then 580 characters, link works. When it does reach the limit, the read more link does work. Any advice or help please and thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var stylistText = $('#stylistText');
var stylistText2 = document.getElementById("stylistText").innerHTML;
var countActualText = stylistText2.valueOf().length;
var maxLength = 580;
var aElement = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode(" ...Read more");
aElement.appendChild(linkText);
aElement.href = "#";

if (countActualText > maxLength) {
    stylistText.text(stylistText.text().substring(0, 580));       
    stylistText.append(aElement);
   }
});
```

here is the html

```
    <div class="stylistInfo">        
        <img id="stylistPhoto" src="images/Test.jpg" alt="peekaboo beans stylist" />
        <p id="stylistText">
            <a href="sdf">This is supposed to be a link</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nec mauris odio. Sed varius, felis eget rutrum scelerisque, enim ligula porta nulla, id rhoncus orci nisi at nunc. Fusce cursus, libero a sagittis viverra, arcu eros luctus arcu, sit amet euismod sapien purus quis nisl. Praesent aliquam aliquam ante ornare pulvinar. Mauris ultrices dictum quam, at ornare dui blandit id. Sed erat elit, fringilla quis diam at, euismod rhoncus massa. Curabitur at arcu nisl. Nullam tincidunt lacus sapien, sed porttitor odio sodales sit amet. Nunc tincidunt nisi et nulla aliquam cras amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis nec mauris odio. Sed varius, felis eget rutrum scelerisque, enim ligula porta nulla, id rhoncus orci nisi at nunc. Fusce cursus, libero a sagittis viverra, arcu eros luctus arcu, sit amet euismod sapien purus quis nisl. Praesent aliquam aliquam ante ornare pulvinar. Mauris ultrices dictum quam, at ornare dui blandit id. Sed erat elit, fringilla quis diam at, euismod rhoncus massa. Curabitur at arcu nisl. Nullam tincidunt lacus sapien, sed porttitor odio sodales sit amet. Nunc tincidunt nisi et nulla aliquam cras amet.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `stylistText.text(stylistText.text().substring(0, 580));`
to `stylistText.html(stylistText.html().substring(0, 580));`

However, truncating a block of text that contains HTML may cause other problems, especially if the truncation occurs in the middle of an element.  I would recommend rethinking your whole strategy on this.

Comment: Thanks man. this did help. and ya ill clean up my code thanks again